# Windows 10 pygame joystick can not read only one of the axis (z-rotation)

Tags: windows, pygame, axis, joystick

I am running Windows 10. I want to use pygame to read the (Thrustmaster steering wheel) joystick axis and buttons. I can read all the values correctly expect one axis (z-rotation, which I read from the default game controller for windows). That axis can be detected, but the value the program returns does not change is I press the pedal. There are two pedals, and the other one works perfectly fine.

Disclaim:

1. The wheel is working, because I can read all the axis from the windows game controller (default one)
2. Before, I ran an older version of Windows 10 on another laptop, the same code works Perfectly fine. When I tried it on my new bought PC, it does not work. Could it be the case, some stupid windows update cause the problem? How should I resolve this? I can not rollback Windows, because it is a fresh new PC, there is no return point for me.

Any insight on this will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you installed pygame correctly, it may not necessarily be the fault of Windows Updates. You should also ensure that you're using Python 3.6 for pygame.

https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Windows%20installation

You may also want to check out their IRC for help assuming that there is an issue with Windows Updates, it could be a bug in their software. There's more info on that here:

https://www.pygame.org/wiki/info

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks a lot for your answer. I am using Python 2.7.13. Do you think that causes the problem? All my programs were written in Python2 instead of Python3.

Comment: The downloads for the build that accepts Python 2.7 can be found here http://python-gaming.com/pygame/downloads.html

Comment: Thanks Rob again. I installed pygame using pip install pygame. The version gets installed is pygame 1.9.3. This version runs fine on an slightly earlier version of Windows 10, but not on my new bought PC. 

I sent an email to the pygame dev community. Hope to hear some voice from there as well ;)